# Identification of this attribute clause

Tags: clauses, parsing

> Anyone for whom this period wasn't so prosperous or miraculous is mentioned only as collateral damage from the oil and rail wars.

Is this sentence an attribute clause?

*However, the  antecedent (Anyone) on which the subordinate clause(this period wasn't so prosperous or miraculous is mentioned) is grammatically independent.*

Can anyone explain the grammar for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence contains an attributive clause, also called an adjective clause, and the clause "for whom this period wasn't so prosperous ..." restricts the meaning of 'anyone'. The word 'anyone' is the antecedent of 'whom', which is the object of the 
preposition 'for'. So, the set of people ('anyone') who are regarded as collateral damage includes all who did not prosper.